# couldn't write specific content into stringstream

Tags: c++, linux

I have some sample code reading some binary data from file and then writing the content into stringstream.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

std::stringstream * raw_data_buffer;
int main()
{
  std::ifstream is;
  is.open ("1.raw", std::ios::binary );

  char * buf = (char *)malloc(40);
  is.read(buf, 40);

  for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    printf("%02X ", buf[i]);

  printf("\n");

  raw_data_buffer = new std::stringstream("", std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
  raw_data_buffer -> write(buf, 40);

  const char * tmp = raw_data_buffer -> str().c_str();
  for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    printf("%02X ", tmp[i]);
  printf("\n");

  delete raw_data_buffer;
  return 0;
}
```

With a specific input file I have, the program doesn't function correctly. You could download the test file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12wLPoIJFlmr9KPZV09tpGEzCvrEERmqQ).

So the problem is, I write the file content into `raw_data_buffer` and immediately read it back, and the content differs. The program's output is:

```
FFFFFFC0 65 59 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FFFFFFE0 0A 40 00 00 00 00 00 FFFFFF80 08 40 00 00 00 00 00 70 FFFFFFA6 57 6E FFFFFFFF 7F 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FFFFFFE0 0A 40 00 00 00 00 00 FFFFFF80 08 40 00 00 00 00 00 70 FFFFFFA6 57 6E FFFFFFFF 7F 00 00
```

The content `FFFFFFC0 65 59 01` is overwritten with 0. Why so?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, which suggests that there may be undefined behavior somewhere. I suggest you [simplify the example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can produce the error with 40 bytes of data; try to produce it with two, or one. And try hard-coding the data, instead of reading it from a file.

Comment: why do you use `malloc`? why do you dynamically allocate a `stringstream`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this a symptom of undefined behavior from using deallocated memory. You're [getting a copy of the string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) from the stringstream but you're only grabbing a raw pointer to the internals that is then immediately deleted. (the link actually warns against this exact case)

```
const char* tmp = raw_data_buffer->str().c_str();
                                // ^^^^^ returns a temporary that is destroyed
                                //       at the end of this statement
//          ^^^ now a dangling pointer
```

Any use of `tmp` would exhibit undefined behavior and could easily cause the problem you're seeing. Keep the result of `str()` in scope.